# PyQt5: Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_style_get: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

I'm getting this error with PyQt5, and I think I get this error only when I use QTextEdit. I tried using QLineEdit in the place of QTextEdit and it worked without problem. Using QTextEdit when I open the program I get that error and the program runs very slow. Error:`(python:4843): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_style_get: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed`

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QLabel, QLineEdit, 
    QTextEdit, QGridLayout, QApplication)


class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        title = QLabel('Title')
        author = QLabel('Author')
        review = QLabel('Review')

        titleEdit = QLineEdit()
        authorEdit = QLineEdit()
        reviewEdit = QTextEdit()

        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.setSpacing(10)

        grid.addWidget(title, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(titleEdit, 1, 1)

        grid.addWidget(author, 2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(authorEdit, 2, 1)

        grid.addWidget(review, 3, 0)
        grid.addWidget(reviewEdit, 3, 1, 5, 1)

        self.setLayout(grid) 

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Review')   
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem. Changing the style of the application
didn't show the error and everything worked properly.

**Corrected Code:**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("fusion") #Changing the style
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

More about styles here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/gallery.html

Comment: I got huge number of Gtk-CRITICAL when running very simple PyQt4 test application from ipython3, that runs fine with no errors under standalone python3. Adding app.setStyle("fusion") removed all of these errors under ipython3 as well. Thank you for the tip.